# What is the name of the parameters sent to a custom validation method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have created two custom validation methods, `profilePhotoWidth` and `profilePhotoHeight`, and when I use them I also send a parameter. How do I get this parameter for the error message? What is the word named to be replaced?

```
<?php
$validator = Validator::make(
    Input::all(),
    [ 
        'logo' => ['mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif', 'max:1024', 'profilePhotoWidth:300', 'profilePhotoHeight:300']
    ],
    [ 
        'logo.profile_photo_width' => 'Max photo width is :??? px.',
        'logo.profile_photo_height' => 'Max photo height is :??? px.'
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

by default there are 2 parameters: `:key` and `:message`

Comment: `:key` is the field to validate. `:message` is untouched.